# Ethereum Blocksci parser tool

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I need a blocksci parser for ethereum. I am using `https://github.com/citp/BlockSci` for bitcoin . Is any similar blocksci parsing tool for ethereum?.

Answer (score 2):

if i understode the question correctly i thinks this is what you are locking for :

https://github.com/alex-miller-0/Ethereum_Blockchain_Parser

This is a project to parse the Ethereum blockchain from a local geth node. Blockchains are perfect data sets because they contain every transaction ever made on the network. This is valuable data if you want to analyze the network, but Ethereum stores its blockchain in RLP encoded binary blobs within a series of LevelDB files and these are surprisingly difficult to access, even given the available tools. This project takes the approach of querying a local node via JSON-RPC, which returns unencoded transactional data, and then moves that data to a mongo database.

Comment: Looks like it's no longer actively maintained (https://github.com/alex-miller-0/Ethereum_Blockchain_Parser/commit/3c7f818a57946d8ee6b55a1cc3fb820e4920f928) :(